# How to initialize a global array that holds pointers to structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm brand new to C and am trying to create a global array that will hold pointers to structs:

```
person* persons[n];
```

However, I need to make the above a global variable. To do that, I need to declare it outside of all functions. But how can I do that without knowing what n will be? Really lost here, any help would be appreciated!

The below is what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish:

```
person* persons[];

function () {
    initialize global array here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a pointer of a pointers and call `malloc` in an init function.

```
person **persons;
int n = 42;

void init(void)
{
    persons = malloc(n * sizeof *persons);
    if (!persons) {
        /* handle malloc failure here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I still use the indices to refer to structs from this new pointer of pointers (as I would in a regular array that holds pointers)?

Comment: @Vimzy yes, for example `persons[0]` is the first `person *` of the array object.

Comment: @Nevermind, that was my bad. My only problem now is can I still do code like this: "persons[h] = (person *) malloc(sizeof(person))" I'm a little new to this "pointer to pointer" thing with structs.

Comment: Because ultimately my code needs this: "persons[h]->name = .." but I'm not sure if this will work?

Comment: @Vimzy yes it will but be sure to initialize all the `persons[i]` first using `malloc` as well.

Comment: Just to state that clear: this is a pointer to pointer, not an array! (Not saying the approach is wrong). So you cannot just e.g. take the size of the array with `sizeof(persons)`.